# Wordpress pages available under multiple URLs by adding /2/, /3/, etc

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting, seo, permalinks

For some reason a Wordpress page is available not only on the intended permalink, but by adding /2/, /3/, /4/, ... to the URL, the same site shows up.

**Example from a random Wordpress Page**

http://chicago.suntimes.com/entertainment/kokandys-the-wiz-really-isnt-in-kansas-anymore/
http://chicago.suntimes.com/entertainment/kokandys-the-wiz-really-isnt-in-kansas-anymore/2/

Could this potentially have an impact on search engines?

Answer (score 0):

All my Wordpress sites are the same I think it's probably available on the numbered urls as something to do with pagination but it won't have an impact on SEO. All of you author, date, taxonomy pages etc also exist by default in a Wordpress install due to the Template Hierarchy